# I can ssh cirros but not centos VM, though I can ping the IP, using Openstack

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack

I have 2 VMs, one contains cirros Image, the other contains Centos7 image. I could ssh into both yesterday. Nothing changed, but I cannot ssh into my Centos VM today, but can still ssh into Cirros VM. I tried creating more VMs, but face the same problem. 
I am using Openstack(Miataka)

Comment: check the logs, edit your question to add more details ...and consider asking on ask.openstack.org too

Comment: Please check if SSH ports are up and also check if default security group is blocking(provided you are accessing ssh from outside network)

Comment: I am sshing both. So if it would block one, it would also block other.

Answer (score 0):

May be ssh server is not installed in those VM, just like when we boot a new Ubuntu machine, we need to install openssh-server in order to ssh into new machine.